# How Can I Record Website As Video using Python?

Tags: python

Similar to how you can add a browser source into OBS and record a website, I need to be able to make a script to do basically exactly that from Python. I need to be able to give a URL to a function to have it start recording a website and outputting it to a video file, and then I need to be able to call another function to stop the recording and save the video.

How best could I go about doing this? Ideally, it would be able to capture both audio and video, but the audio isn't really that important.

I've tried the Selenium screenshot method, but that records at around 3 frames per second.

Thanks for any help anyone is able to provide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [record a web page using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172501/record-a-web-page-using-python)

Comment: It needs to do this headlessly, so no, I don't think so. I did quite a bit of googling before I asked.

Comment: if you can use javascript: https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-recorder

Comment: Yeah I can probably use JavaScript

Comment: Okay, I have tried that, and it's recording at an event lower framerate than what I was doing with Selenium manually.